# What does blank output for a Ansible task mean?

Tags: ansible

I've got 3 tasks which output the following:

```
TASK [apache: Apache Task A] ****************************
Friday 29 September 2017  12:35:12 +0100 (0:00:00.050)       0:00:01.026 ****** 
skipping: [host1]

TASK [apache: Apache Task B] *********************************
Friday 29 September 2017  12:35:12 +0100 (0:00:00.038)       0:00:01.064 ****** 
ok: [host1]

TASK [apache: Apache Task C] ***********************
Friday 29 September 2017  12:35:12 +0100 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:01.105 ******
```

I understand `skipping` and `ok` but what does it mean when there's no output?

FWIW, Apache Task C contains an empty list variable so my understanding is that this output means something like `skipping` or `nothing to do`.

Is that correct?

Comment: You haven't shown us what the tasks are that are being run. Also, `-vvvv`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Empty response is for loops with empty lists to iterate.